# Beginners Japanese learning resources

Tags: learning, resources

I want to learn Japanese Language by myself.

I googled around and there are some resources but due to the fact that I have absolutely no idea what I could be missing, I was looking for some well thought out answers about what learning materials will be a good start.

I have no previous experience in Japanese. I need something that's based or feedback, has a relatively slow pace and includes exercise materials. I prefer very lengthy courses.

My native language is Bengali.

Comment: i think this is a q for the meta site. The answer is subjective but I would suggest "Japanese for busy people"( - you might find better advice on the meta site).

Comment: For people who has down-voted this please, make an attempt to marge the information of this question : [Resources for learning Japanese](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/756/resources-for-learning-japanese) with FAQ. Would save someone else from trouble.

Answer (score 2):

The stackexchange network is designed for a very fairly specific question and answer format. Questions that don't have an authoritative or demonstrable answer aren't a good fit for sites like JLU. Because of this, I expect this question will be closed and/or moved to meta as soon as a moderator sees it.

You might be interested in looking at our [resources list](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/756/resources-for-learning-japanese), a number of us have put this list together to share resources that we have found useful while studying Japanese.

In addition, I'd encourage you to drop by the [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/511/japanese-language-and-usage), since we don't require the same focus there. (The chatroom is also considered to be the 'help area' for the resources list)

Comment: I was hoping someone would turn it into a community wiki. Lot of questions that aren't suited for direct answer get turned into that. Its not rare.